# Switchbox within <include> set themselves upon configuration change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am experiencing very strange behaviour when I use `switchboxes` within `<include>` tags. Minimal example:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:id="@+id/fragment"
          android:name="com.fimagena.myapplication.MainActivityFragment"
          tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include android:id="@+id/inc1" layout="@layout/includelayout" />
    <include android:id="@+id/inc2" layout="@layout/includelayout" />
    <include android:id="@+id/inc3" layout="@layout/includelayout" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**includelayout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Switch"
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**MainActivityFragment.java**

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        ((Switch) root.findViewById(R.id.inc1).findViewById(R.id.switch1)).setChecked(false);
        ((Switch) root.findViewById(R.id.inc2).findViewById(R.id.switch1)).setChecked(false);
        ((Switch) root.findViewById(R.id.inc3).findViewById(R.id.switch1)).setChecked(false);

        return root;
    }
}
```

What I would expect: An empty fragment with 3 switches that are always resetting themselves to unchecked upon configuration change (since Activity and Fragment get reconstructed.)

What I am getting: 3 switches that are always resetting themselves to whatever state the 3rd switch was in when the configuration change occurs (i.e., when I rotate the phone).

Is this a bug or am I missing something? Given that I explicitly use `setChecked(false)` on all 3 switches, they should not be able to set themselves to on in any case. The configuration change works fine, the `Activity` and `Fragment` are reconstructed, `onCreateView()` is called as expected. Nevertheless the state of all 3 switches is determined by the last one, not by my `setChecked()` calls.

I assume it has something to do with the fact that all switches have the same id, since they're included from the same XML. They are identified correctly though, I can, for example, call `setEnabled()` on one switch and only that switch is affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never faced this issue since I normally use different ids in my layouts. I believe the problem is that Android maintains view states internally by their ids.

You use same ids for all your Checks, so you need to save/restore their states by your own. Be cautious, you have to restore view states inside [onViewStateRestored](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewStateRestored(android.os.Bundle)). This will ensure your view states not be overwritten by system. The following code snippet should work.

**MainActivityFragment.java**

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Switch;

public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment
        implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivityFragment";

    private Switch mSwitch1;
    private Switch mSwitch2;
    private Switch mSwitch3;

    private boolean mRestoreFlag = false;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView");
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        mSwitch1 = (Switch) root.findViewById(R.id.inc1).findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        mSwitch2 = (Switch) root.findViewById(R.id.inc2).findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        mSwitch3 = (Switch) root.findViewById(R.id.inc3).findViewById(R.id.switch1);


        mSwitch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        mSwitch2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        mSwitch3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (!mRestoreFlag) {
            return;
        }
        if (buttonView == mSwitch1) {
            Log.d(TAG, "switch1.isChecked()=" + isChecked);
        } else if (buttonView == mSwitch2) {
            Log.d(TAG, "switch2.isChecked()=" + isChecked);
        } else if (buttonView == mSwitch3) {
            Log.d(TAG, "switch3.isChecked()=" + isChecked);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
        outState.putBoolean("switch1", mSwitch1.isChecked());
        outState.putBoolean("switch2", mSwitch2.isChecked());
        outState.putBoolean("switch3", mSwitch3.isChecked());
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onViewStateRestored");
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "restore savedInstanceState");
            mSwitch1.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("switch1", false));
            mSwitch2.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("switch2", false));
            mSwitch3.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("switch3", false));
        }
        mRestoreFlag = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had stripped out the loading/saving of state in my example but what you're telling me is that the `setChecked()` state needs to be set in `onViewStateRestored()` and not in `onViewCreated()`. This makes it work, thanks! Is there a clear rationale for this or is it a bug? Other properties (e.g., `setEnabled()`) seem to have no problem with `onViewCreated()`...

Comment: After some further testing, it looks like that in general within `onViewCreated()`, Android cannot differentiate the 3 switches, while in `onViewStateRestored()` it can. I was running into the same problem again with `setOnCheckedChangeListener()`... They should mention this somewhere in the documentation for `<include>`. Talk about hard to track bugs... :-(

Comment: @mmumpitz Android restore switch state in [CompoundButton.onRestoreInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Parcelable)). But setEnabled is not the part of state that will be restored.

Comment: @mmumpitz I've updated my answer to add a workaround for setOnCheckedChangeListener. You can check it out :-)